# How to replace array values to same+10

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

How I can replace elements?
I try like this, but it does not work

```
    NSMutableArray* marray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

for (int i = 0; [marray count]; i++) {        
    NSInteger curentVal = [[marray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    curentVal += 5;
    [marray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:curentVal];
}
```

Comment: not related but don't you need i < [marray count]; in your for loop?

Comment: There were no error messages when you tried to compile the above??

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `curentVal` back to an object, in this case a `NSString`.

There is also a typeo in the `for` statement.

```
NSMutableArray* marray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
NSLog(@"marray: %@", marray);

for (NSInteger i = 0; i<[marray count]; i++) {
    NSInteger curentVal = [[marray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    curentVal += 5;
    NSString *curentValString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)curentVal];
    [marray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject: curentValString];
}
NSLog(@"marray: %@", marray);
```

Output:

```
marray: (
    1,
    2,
    3
)
marray: (
    6,
    7,
    8
)
```

Here is the same approach with `NSNumbers`:

```
NSMutableArray* marray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@1, @2, @3, nil];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i<[marray count]; i++) {
    NSInteger curentVal = [[marray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    curentVal += 5;
    [marray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@(curentVal)];
}
```

Comment: But they are starting with strings, not numbers.

Comment: One more suggestion - change `i` to `NSInteger` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

curentVal is not an object. You should put:

```
 [marray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@(curentVal)];
```

so curentVal is converted to an NSNumber

Also you probably want to deal with numbers, so put:

```
NSMutableArray* marray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@1, @2, @3, nil];
```